# Wi-Fi signal "around" concrete floor

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My house has three floors. The two bottom floors are separated by a concrete floor and unfortunately concrete blocks Wi-Fi signals quite effectively. I tested using a mesh network earlier, but it was unreliable (good signal 90% of the time).

My question is this:

I realize that this is not optimal, but will the Wi-Fi signal be stronger if I place them as shown in the images below, or is that just a waste of effort?

[image]

[image]

I realize that the signal strength will be reduced if it has to go "around" the floor, but will it, despite that, add to the strength of the signal going through the concrete, thus making the total a bit better?

If this is futile; do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The most reliable suggestion is putting a hole through the concrete floor and feeding an ethernet cable through it.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not an alternative.

Comment: Presumably there is a hole between the floors for something like a staircase. Can you locate the router near that hole?

Comment: It's an apartment with its own entrance. There's a single ethernet cable going down which is used for TV-signals. TV is included in the rent, so we can't substitute the TV signals with internet. According to the broadband and TV provider, using one cable for both is impossible.

Comment: Usually that means either "It'll need some hardware and skill that most of our customers generally don't have" and/or "We don't feel like taking phone calls to officially support that kind of setup". Where does the cable come from, and does the cable go into the TV's LAN/Ethernet port, or does it go into the TV's antenna port? If it's _actual_ Ethernet, then the TV signal is just a VLAN for the IPTV, and many providers run both over the same cable by default. Only if it's actual RF over that cable then it's a problem.

Comment: You might be right, I'm not sure. The cable goes from the "home central" provided by the service provider to a decoder (also by the service provider). The home central has four lan ports: PC (internet), Tv, Tv, Tv. We can't connect the wifi router to a tv-port, and can't connect a decoder to the PC port.

Comment: If it comes from a regular LAN port then it's really just Ethernet data (usually just IP) that could be put in a VLAN alongside Internet. Some ISPs do that as part of their standard configuration (to let the actual TV access the LAN). Externally, it might be $200 for two VLAN-capable Ethernet switches on both ends of the cable... Do you have a computer with Ethernet that you could install Wireshark on, and take a look at what it sees on one of the "TV" ports?

Comment: First thing I'd try would be a directional WiFi antenna, perhaps feeding into a WiFi "dongle" with connection for an external antenna (it's more difficult to access the WiFi adapter in most laptops). A *cantenna* can be constructed for little more than the price of cable and connector: https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Cantenna . and a WiFi adapter can be US$12 or less, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Desktop-ALINKVITE-Adapters-Wireless/dp/B09JBZZ8VF/ref=sr_1_25